# Cannot lock file hash cache when gradle was aborted

Tags: gradle, locking

I canceled a running Gradle build and now I get the following message whenever I restart it:

```
Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionServices.createFileHasher().
   > Cannot lock file hash cache (/data/.gradle/6.4.1/fileHashes) as it has already been locked by this process.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to look for the gradle process and to kill it. In my case I had to look for a running java process.

So in htop I searched for `java` and terminated it. That solved my problem.

Comment: Running `gradlew --stop` is less of a hassle and more elegant.

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me.  Neither `gradle` nor `gradlew` were on my path outside of the IDE and `--stop` was not an obvious option from within the IDE.  Hunting the stray `java` job was easier than trying to resolve that.

Answer (score 97):

try running (if gradle in installed on your machine and in the PATH)

```
gradle --stop
```

or

```
./gradlew --stop
```

in your project directory
from the command line. worked for me.

Comment: Use `gradlew` if you are using a wrapper, but `gradle` should work if you are running the right version/have the right path

Comment: after gradle --stop the deamon endid, but still this error appeared.

Had to restart Intellij before I could restart my application. This happens to me sometimes in case of certain exceptions.

Answer (score 37):

run

```
gradlew --stop
```

in the terminal for Windows

For Mac user run

```
./gradlew --stop
```

from root of you project

Comment: @PouriaHemati go to the terminal of the android studio and run the command .

Comment: ./gradlew --stop

Answer (score 1):

Remove the lock files in the gradle cache by executing something like this:

> find ~/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" -delete

Comment: this is the solution that worked for me on linux